# How to create an object and then set related field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new object using Django REST Framework's `ModelViewSet` and the `ModelSerializer` and associate an existing object to it's `ForeignKey` field. I have two models with a one-to-many relationship, basically a manufacturer and a product. The manufacturer already exists in the database and I'm trying to add a product individually and assign it's manufacturer at the same time. When I do, DRF is giving me this error:

> "non_field_errors": [
>       "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Product."
>   ]

Here are what my models look like (I've tried to take out the unneeded code to keep it small). When a product is created the `manufacturer` field is an integer representing the ID of it's related object. As you can see in my view, I query for the `Manufacturer` object, set it and then continue to let DRF create the object. If someone can please tell me where I'm going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it!

**models.py**

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Product(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name="products")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductViewSet(view sets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Product
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get logged in user's manufacturer
        return Product.objects.filter(manufacturer=manufacturer)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "manufacturer" in request.data:
            manufacturer = Manufacturer.objects.get(pk=request.data["manufacturer"])
            request.data["manufacturer"] = manufacturer

        return super(ProductViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ManufacturerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        fields = ("id", "name", "state",)
        read_only_fields = ("id",)

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("id", "manufacturer", "name",)
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set `manufacturer_id` key.

change your serializer to:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer(read_only=True)
    manufacturer_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("id", "manufacturer", "name",)
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
```

change your create method to:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "manufacturer" in request.data:
        request.data["manufacturer_id"] = request.data['manufacturer']

    return super(ProductViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This works for inserts and kind of works for updates. For example, I have a product "X" that belongs to manufacturer "A". I update "X" to have a new manufacturer "B". The object returned to me from the `update` method still shows "A" as the manufacturer but the database was actually updated to "B". If I refresh the page it has the correct value. I've gone through the DRF code and can't seem to understand why this is the case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I overrode the `update` method in my serializer and called `instance.refresh_from_db()` and that seems to have solved it. It feels kind of "hacky" but it works.